"Trying to read MMMM from 18 MAY 2028 at 3"
When I use either DateTime parsedDate = DateFormat('d MMMM yyyy').parse(editablelist.value!.text); or DateTime parsedDate = DateFormat('d MMMM y').parse(editablelist.value!.text);, I encounter the error "Trying to read MMMM from 18 MAY 2028 at 3"
      if(editablelist.value!.text.contains(" ")){
    print("ONLY_SPACE");
      // Attempt to parse the input date string
      DateTime parsedDate = DateFormat('d MMMM y').parse(editablelist.value!.text);
      print("PASRSE_DATE, $parsedDate");

      // Convert the parsed date back to a string using the same format
      String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(parsedDate);

      print("FORMATED_DATE , $formattedDate");

      // Check if the formatted date matches the original string
      if (formattedDate == editablelist.value!.text) {
        print('The format matches: ${editablelist.value!.text}');
      } else {
        print('The format does not match: ${editablelist.value!.text}');
      }

      String formattedDateForComparison = "${formattedDate.replaceAll(" ", "-").split("-")[2]}-${formattedDate.replaceAll(" ", "-").split("-")[1]}-${formattedDate.replaceAll(" ", "-").split("-")[0]}T00:00:00.000";

      if (DateTime.parse(formattedDateForComparison).compareTo(DateTime.now()) < 0) {
        print("Expired");
        expired1 = true;
        AppUtils().showToast("The Document is Expired", context);
        return OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red));
      } else {
        print("NotExpired2");
        expired1 = false;
        return OutlineInputBorder();
      }
    }


For it to match MMMM is needs to be May, not MAY. Capitalization matters

https://github.com/dart-lang/i18n/issues/817
